# Can I modify the name of the email that comes when I do the mention on the Chatter?

Tags: chatter, email-alert

[image]

As shown in the screen above, the contents of Chatter will be sent to me via e-mail when I do the Mention on Chatter. Can I customize the title of that red circle?

Answer (score 0):

This is a salesforce standard functionality that cannot be changed or updated.   Kindly review [Idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HA1sAAG) for same and vote for this feature.

Thanks